# Powering Raspberry Pi Zero and a HUB with one charger (3 in 1 cable)

Tags: power-supply, cable, usb-hub

I'm planning to buy the latest Raspberry Pi (Zero) and I'm trying to figure something out. Let's assume I have a decent power supply (2A) and I'm using this cable for powering it and powering an USB HUB.

### [image: A strange 3 in 1 cable]

Connections:

1. Male Micro USB: connected to Raspberry Pi
2. Male USB: connected to a charger (2A)
3. Female USB: connected to a HUB

Will this setup provide:

1. power to Raspberry Pi **AND**
2. extra power to a HUB **AND**
3. connection between Raspberry Pi and a HUB

?

I'm planning to attach a Wi-Fi plug and an external USB drive to the HUB so the HUB should also be powered by a charger (just in case). I heard mixed opinions about this setup. I have to be sure it will work like a charm.

Why not 2 output charger, the first one to the Pi, the second one to the HUB? Well, I'm thinking of this HUB (I love it) and it requires an extra charger (not USB standard).

[image: An awesome HUB I want to buy]

EDIT:

I decided not to use this cable. I'm simply going to buy a hub with the exact same form factor as the Pi Zero and combine the devices. It's called an USB Hub Mod and it's easy to Google.

Look for: 
"Raspberry Pi Zero – USB Hub Mod" & 
"Raspberry Pi Zero Piggy-Back USB Hub"

I'm not posting the link. Links are not permanent.

However the question I posted is rather interesting so if someone is going to try this cable I'll be glad to accept the solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible it may work.

If you plug the big USB into the HUB and your power supply USB into the big USB which is plugged intot he HUB, then the small USB into the Pi power, that should provide power to everything.

Then you plug the USB HUB, USB host cable into the Pi and that should recognise the HUB in Raspian.

Theoretically you will have 3 usable USB ports to use then.

It is a bit strange way of doing it, but you have the cable that can do it. So it should be OK as the **USB connection on the Zero does not seem to be connected to 5v, so you cant power the Pi via the USB, only via Power**. If it was, you could back power form the HUB. As long as you don't use any other power supplies in the circuit it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend a lot based on what you want to plug into it. The RPi Zero will need at least 100 mA (though this is a minimum; you will need more at higher loads). Your hub and other devices will have their own requirements. Add these up and if they're under the power supply's output, you have a good chance.

Comment: I know that. The issue is whether this cable can provide power to both devices "separately" and moreover whether the Pi could recognize the HUB at the same time. I'm reading some stuff about this cable and apparently big male port have to be connected to the host, not the power supply. I'm not sure though. If so the question is pointless. I cannot find a detailed specification of the cable. Perhaps someone is using it so he/she can write more about this setup.

Comment: Yeah, without trying it then, it's hard to say for sure.  If you decide to try, be sure to let us know.

Comment: Hi Jacob, I think it should read *mA* not *mAh*. And 100 mA is more or less the Pi idling only with higher consumption possible at higher load.

Comment: @Ghanima: you are correct about my notation. I thought at least made it relatively clear, but I'll add a note about higher loads. Thanks for pointing it out.